# Why do I get a syntax error in MySQL involving if statement and throwing of exception mentioned on StackOverflow?

Tags: mysql

What is the error in this code (Assuming that `teacher` exists)? This code keeps giving me syntax errors in mysql workbench but it works fine in vscode.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER teacher_add_validation AFTER INSERT ON teacher FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.Account LIKE '% %' THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "No spaces allowed in account names.";
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: show the error message

Comment: @BerndBuffen 19:32:40 CREATE TRIGGER stu_add_validation AFTER INSERT ON student FOR EACH ROW IF NEW.Account LIKE '% %' THEN  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No spaces allowed in account names.' Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3 0.000 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have the **DELIMITER** ??

```
set DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER teacher_add_validation AFTER INSERT ON teacher FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.Account LIKE '% %' THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "No spaces allowed in account names.";
END IF;
END;

//
SET DELIMITER ;
```

see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delimiters/